# in ipad simulator how to set screen size to 1x 2x format

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-simulator, iphone-sdk-4.1

For my App I have set the target device family=iPhone/iPad

and in project-> Set Active executable to iPad simulator and it was opening my App in iPad simulator in 1x/2x format so i could change the size by using option 1x 2x.

now i have upgrated my IOS SDK to 4.2 from 4.1

the probleam is: now my App opens in the iPad simulator with full screen size(instead of 1x 2x format) and all controls'  position on the screen has been changed  and it spoiled whole look of app.

now I want to open my app in iPad simulator again in the same 1x 2x scrren sizes format.

so now How I can do that?

please help and suggest

thanks

Comment: What 1x 2x format? I don't get it. Are you trying to open an iPhone app pixel-doubled on the iPad simulator or do you think there's a hi-res version of the iPad simulator?

Comment: ya I am trying to open my iPhone app in the iPad simulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 1x/2x option is only a compatibility option for iPhone-only apps.  If you set the targeted device family to iPhone/iPad, then it is a universal app and will always display at full resolution on the iPad.